# Is $D_{∞}^{(2)}$ virtually abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, dihedral-groups

I know that $D_{∞}^{(2)}$ is the set of all bijections: $f: \mathbb{Z}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{2}$ such that $d(f(x),f(y))=d(x,y)$.

So the group multiplication is given by the composition of functions.

I also know that the distance between two points $x=(x_{1},x_{2}), y= (y_{1},y_{2})$ is given by:
 d(x,y)=$\sqrt{(x_{1}-y_{1})^{2}+(x_{2}-y_{2})^{2}}$

Now I want to know if $D_{∞}^{(2)}$ is virtually abelian. In other words if there is a subgroup H of $D_{∞}^{(2)}$ such that it is abelian ($\forall x,y\in H:  xy=yx$) and has finite index ( $\dfrac{|D_{∞}^{(2)}|}{|H|}\neq ∞$).

I believe $D_{∞}^{(2)}$ is indeed virtually abelian because $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ satisfies the criteria is this correct?

Comment: I just don't understand why you say " $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ [...] can't be a subgroup because it isn't cyclic" . Of course it is a subgroup, and it is abelian. It is indeed not cyclic, but why should this matter?

Comment: $\mathbb Z^2$ is a subgroup. Indeed for all $(a,b)\in \mathbb Z^2$, you get a distance preserving bijection $(x,y)\mapsto(x+a,y+b)$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that the image of a straight line is still a straight line, otherwise the distance preserving would be violated (on non successive points). Secondly, note that the image of a grid is still a grid. Note that the only distance preserving bijections are translations, vertical and horizontal symmerties and rotations over mutiples of $90°$. Conclude that yoru group is the semidirect product of the translations $\mathbb{Z}^2$ over the dihedral group $D_8$ with eight elements.